# Definitive list of what is not allowed in Windows Phone apps?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've just started messing around with Windows Phone development, and I'm looking for some resources that describe what is off limits.

For example, I've gathered that it is not possible to create a custom system theme, or even modify a theme, which was unexpected.  In the MSDN, there are references to the 10 defaults, and it makes mention that operators and OEMs can add an 11th, but I haven't found anything that says "Thou shalt not make a theme".

Comment: such a list would be infinite in length. Look at what you CAN do and then everything else is off limits.

Comment: Okay, so where is that list?  Are you saying if something doesn't have a How-To article, it can't be done?

Comment: The most comprehensive list of what is possible can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I think you should make this the an answer and I'll mark it as such. That looks like it's going to be as close to an answer to the original question as we get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a list would be infinite in length. Look at what you CAN do and then everything else is off limits.

The most comprehensive list of what is possible can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402535(v=vs.92).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to have a look at [the requirements of the Marketplace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184843%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

There is also a [Marketplace Test Kit in the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394032%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that can help you to check your code and give a nice overview.

These list show mainly what is required and what is not allowed. The rest seems to be allowed.

Being able (or not) is not the same as not being allowed. A list like that would be too long.

Comment: I hadn't seen that Test Kit. I'll take a look at that. Thank you.  I've been through the requirements site and it no point did it say you couldn't change themes, or even that you can't mess with the settings. The only thing I could see as applicable is the very vague "Applications do not interfere with the phone functionality".  "Interfere" is pretty subjective, and I'm not seeing their definition for that too.

Comment: My guess is that it is nearly impossible to pin everything down. People can always think of more things to do than you can foresee. By stating intentions/correct behavior and keeping it broad you should be able to (more or less) guess what is and isn't allowed. At the same time they will be able to stop any bad things that they didn't think of. It's easy: make an app, stay away from other apps and the OS and make the app fit its environment.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, I've gathered that it is not possible to create a custom system theme, or even modify a theme, which was unexpected

You know, it's fairly obvious if you look at how the platform works in general. You can write apps, not modify the OS. That simple.

And no, apps isn't custom keyboards, custom themes, custom launchers, and so on. Apps are, like on Windows, applications you can start, that run their own separate lives.

Comment: I disagree that it is obvious, but maybe that's because I come from an Android background.  I would think something as simple as "don't touch the settings" would be prominently displayed in the documentation, especially for the app certification requirements.

Comment: And putting something like appearance and theme on the same level as a changing core functionality seems... excessive. Are the built-in colors really so perfect that letting you pick a different one would be a serious problem?

Comment: Actually yes. Platform design should be done by the platform designers, not app developers.